# Scala: Checking if 2 variables are of the same type

Tags: scala, types

So I've been trying to check how I would check if 2 variables, x and y, are of the same type.

People have posting about =:=, but that seems to only check if a variable is of the type X.

Could some tricks in pattern matching be used?

Thanks.

Comment: You mean compile-time type or runtime type of two variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For static-type checking at compile-time:

```
def sameType[T, U](a: T, b: U)(implicit evidence: T =:= U) = true
```

and then

```
sameType("abc", "cde") // Returns true
sameType("abc", 123)   // Does not compile
```

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I think your version of sameType always compiles if you don't specify the type parameter, since A is inferred as an upper bound of the types of a and b, and an upper bound always exists (Any).

Comment: You're absolutely right, it will infer the LUB. I'm taking my comment away :)

Answer (score 3):

```
x.getClass() == y.getClass()
```

is applicable at run-time, not compile-time.  Since it is post-type-erasure, any type parameters (Java generics) will be gone - so List[Int].getClass() == List[String].getClass().  This may or may not be useful!